# How to run Gitlab CI only for specific branches and some rules?

Tags: gitlab, continuous-integration, gitlab-ci

I am trying to build ci according to the following criteria:

1. Run only when pushing to master branch - already implemented
2. Run on commit [run ci] - already implemented
3. Manual launch from the Run pipeline - already implemented
4. do not launch when pushing to the master branch when only Tag changes
5. do not start in other cases if they do not fall under the first 3 options

The tag may change without changes in other files and do not need to run the assembly, I tried this

```
if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "master" && $CI_COMMIT_TAG =~ /^$/
```

but it doesn't work if there are changes in both files and tags.

I will be glad to help

My  .gitlab-ci.yml

```
image: busybox:latest

build1:
  stage: build
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_MESSAGE =~ /\[run ci\]/
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "master" 
    - when: manual
      allow_failure: false
  script:
    - echo "Do your build  here"

test1:
  stage: test
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_MESSAGE =~ /\[run ci\]/
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "master" 
    - allow_failure: false
  script:
    - echo "Do a test here"
    - echo "For example run a test suite"

deploy:
  stage: deploy
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_MESSAGE =~ /\[run ci\]/
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "master" 
    - allow_failure: false
  script:
    - echo "Do a test here"
    - echo "For example run a test suite"
```